# Invalid conversion error while passing a dynamic array to a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to C++. I am trying to write a program which can resize an array while running the program. Every time I try to pass the array, it says "Invalid coversion from int to int* [-fpermissive] ". I have tried writing it in another way as well but this error still comes up.
Heres the code I wrote:-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void resizeArray ( int p_int, int startingSize, int new_size );
void printArray ( int p_int, int new_size );

int main ()
{
    int startingSize = 3; // I set this to three in order to avoid confusion
    int *p_int = new int [ startingSize ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < startingSize; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Value of Element [ " << i << "] : " ;
        cin >> p_int [ i ];
    }

    int userInput = 3;// I set this to three in order to avoid confusion
    cout << "How many more would you like to add? :" ;
    cout << userInput << endl;

    int new_size = startingSize + userInput;

    resizeArray ( p_int, startingSize, new_size );

    for ( int i = startingSize; i < new_size; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Value of Element [ " << i << " ] : ";
        cin >> p_int [ i ];
    }

    printArray ( p_int, new_size );

    delete [] p_int;

    return 0;
}

void resizeArray ( int p_int, int startingSize, int new_size )
{
    int *temp = new int [ new_size ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < startingSize; i++ )
       temp [ i ] = p_int [ i ];
    delete [] p_int;

    p_int = temp;
}

void printArray ( int p_int, int new_size )
{
    cout << "~~ Complete Array ~~ " <<endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i < new_size; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Element [ " << i << " ] = " << p_int << endl;
    } 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the function is declared as having type `int`

```
void resizeArray ( int p_int, int startingSize, int new_size );
                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

while you are trying to supply argument of type `int *`.

```
resizeArray ( p_int, startingSize, new_size );
              ^^^^^
```

The same mistake exists for the second function

```
void printArray ( int p_int, int new_size );
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

But if you change the parameter from type `int` to `int *` in any case the function will not work as you are expecting because the argument should be passed by reference.

Also in general case the new size of the array can be less than the original size of the array. Thus the loop that copies elements in the function is also incorrect.

A correct function definition can look the following way

```
void resizeArray ( int * &p_int, size_t starting_size, size_t new_size )
{
    int *temp = nullptr;

    if ( new_size != 0 )
    {

        temp = new int [ new_size ];

        size_t n = new_size < starting_size ? new_size : starting_size;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )   temp [ i ] = p_int [ i ];
    }

    delete [] p_int;

    p_int = temp;
}
```

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested and it worked. but would you please explain what "int * &p_int" means. This is the first time I am seeing something like that.

Comment: @aspire29 It means that the parameter is declared as reference to the supplied argument.  You will learn soon about references.

Answer (score 2):

`int` will never magically interpreted as `int*` or `int*&`. Use proper types for the arguments like this:

```
void resizeArray ( int*& p_int, int startingSize, int new_size );
void printArray ( const int* p_int, int new_size );
```

Don't forget to update both of declaretions and definitions.

I used `int*& p_int` for `resizeArray()` because `p_int` should be a pointer and modifying caller's local variable seems intended.

I used `const int* p_int` for `printArray()` because passing (a pointer to the first element of) array should be intended and modifying the passed array doesn't seem intended.

Also I guess you want to use `p_int[i]` instead of `p_int` in the printing statement in `printArray()`.

Comment: Good call.  Forgot he was modify what the pointer points to.  More than just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `resizeArray` and `printArray` seem to work on `int *` (`p_int` argument) but as a 1. argument you use `int`. Adding `*` should help.

If you write your program as an excercise, its ok, but if you want to do it in `c++` way just use `std::vector<int>`. You will save yourself a lot of troubles :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `int` instead of `int*` or `int* &`.

```
void resizeArray ( int*& p_int, int startingSize, int new_size );
void printArray ( const int* p_int, int new_size );
```